Matrix equation over an orthogonal matrix
Let $\mathrm{diag}(X)$ denote the diagonal elements of a square matrix $X$. Let $A$ denote a (real-valued) $3\times 3$ matrix, whose columns are unit vectors that have been independently and randomly generated according to an isotropic distribution.
I want to solve the following matrix equation over the matrix $U$
$$\mathrm{diag}(UA)=\mathrm{diag}(A)$$
where $U$ is orthogonal, i.e., $U^\mathrm{T}U=I$.
Clearly, $U=I$ is a trivial solution, but I have noted that there are always further solutions, but I cannot prove that this is always the case. Moreover, I have noted that there are always further solutions with such that $\mathrm{det}(U)=1$, i.e., no reflection is needed.

There are not always further solutions. For example, take
$$A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&3}.$$
Multiplying $UA$ essentially multiplies the columns of $U$ by $1$, $2$, and $3$ respectively, from left to right. So, in order for $UA$ and $A$ to share diagonal, we would need
\begin{align}
1(U)_{11} &= 1 \\
2(U)_{22} &= 2 \\
3(U)_{33} &= 3,
\end{align}
i.e. the diagonal of $U$ must be $1, 1, 1$. But, since $U$ is orthogonal, the columns are orthonormal, and hence each has length $1$. So, the presence of a single $1$ in each column implies that zeros must be elsewhere. That is, $U = I$ is the only possibility in this case.
This same argument works for any full-rank diagonal matrix $A$.

Ok, agreed. I wrote to fast. Lets assume that all elements in matrix $A$ are randomly generated, for example from a normal distribution. This is actually what I have in my problem at hand. Then I want to verify that, except for a set of $A$-matrices of measure zero, there are always multiple solutions.

I updated the OP according to the answer and my previous comment
